# mvc slideshow using folders

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, slideshow

I'm brand new to MVC so I figured I would start a simple project that would display a slideshow of images from a series of folders on my local machine to help me learn.  I'm looking for help just to get started.

my slideshow content would be in a folder on my local machine (`C:\SlideshowStuff`).  now I do want to be able to have different slideshows in individual folders within that main folder.  (i.e.: `\SlideshowStuff\KungFu`, `\SlideshowStuff\SciFi`, etc.)

I want to have a page that lists all the folders in the C:\SlideShowStuff\ folder, and when a user clicks on one, it then either loads the slideshow, or the subfolders within the folder (like  `\SlideshowStuff\KungFu\JetLi` or `\Kungfu\JackieChan`) ultimately ending in the user choosing a folder that will display a slideshow.

Since I'm not using a database would I not use a `Model` and base everything in the `Controller`? or would I use the `Model` to grab the content from my local file system and pass the info to the `Controller`?  How many `Views` would actually be needing to created?  I know at least 2, one for the beginning page listing the main folder's contents and another for the slideshow content.  Would I need a third for listing the subfolder content, or would I just reuse a `View`?

Like I said, I'm just starting out with MVC, so I apologize if this is too noobish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since I'm not using a database would I not use a Model and base everything in the Controller?

Models have nothing to do with a database.  Models are your conceptual objects where the business logic of the system resides.  Controllers are just an interface for users to invoke actions in the system, they should in turn invoke the business logic that's on the models.  That logic shouldn't be in the controllers.

> How many Views would actually be needing to created?

For as many structurally different user interfaces as you would have.  Technically you could put everyone on a single view and use JavaScript to show/hide/manipulate content, if you want.  To start off with something simple I imagine you'd have the two views you currently envision, one being the list of slideshows and one being the slideshow itself.

The main thing to keep in mind with MVC is how the different concerns of the components are separated.  Keep in mind the saying, "Keep your controllers light and your models heavy."  More specifically...

1. Views are the user interface.  Therefore they are tightly coupled with user interface concerns.  No sharable logic should go there, only display logic.
2. Controllers are the actions invoked by the user interface.  They are *related to* but not *tightly coupled to* the interface technology (web in this case).  Though they can easily become tightly coupled, you'll learn a lot about that as you continue.  They really just accept input and direct business logic actions in response to that input, nothing more.
3. Models are your business logic.  If you can imagine another application using another technology (let's say a Windows Forms application), the Models are the shared component between these two applications.  They should have no dependency on any UI technology, and they should entirely contain all of the logic needed for any application to perform this same functionality.  (In this case fetching the list of slideshows, images in a slideshow, etc.)

Comment: If I understand correctly, the `Model` would be grabbing the content/data from the local filesystem and passing that to the particular `Controller`-`View` pair. So, does the `Model` determine which `Controller`-`View` pair to use? Meaning if the one the user selects has subfolders does the `Model` choose the `Controller`-`View` pair for displaying the list of folders, and if the one the user selected had the images would the `Model` choose the 'Controller`-`View` pair that would display the slideshow?

Comment: @shadonar: The model doesn't determine anything about the controller/view because the model doesn't *know* about the controller/view.  If it did, it would be tightly coupled to that specific application.  In this case the controller would receive a request for a given folder, initialize a model with the value of that folder (perhaps via a factory method on the model, a repository for the model, etc.), and send that model (or a derived model) to the view for display.  Internal to the model would be the logic for getting the files based on the value received from the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend going through a tutorial that has already been fleshed out for ASP.NET MVC. It seems you are missing core concepts. I mean no disrespect by this.

That said :

> If I understand correctly, the Model would be grabbing the content/data from the local filesystem and passing that to the particular Controller-View pair. So, does the Model determine which Controller-View pair to use?

No it does not. The URL hits the routing engine and that picks a controller to render. The controller then calls out to any service methods (models) it needs and passes the final result to a view.

The project you are trying to create is a bad way to start MVC because there is no need for MVC. What you have requires no business logic (The M part). You would simply be rendering views with images on them.

Remember that design patterns are meant to fit a specific problem. MVC ASP.NET , for the most part, for web apps. The problem you are trying to solve is for a web page not an app.Meaning you are displaying static content instead of processing user input or some other input and displaying output based on processed input.

Answer (score 0):

Model is not necessarily a domain model, it is a model for the view, you will have to declare models class, write the logic in controller to populate data in the view model instance (in your case from file system instead of database) and then render those to the view. Does this help ? or were you looking for something else.